# What's causing my potatoes to wilt?

Tags: diagnosis, potatoes, wilt

I'm growing [yukon gold potatoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukon_Gold_potato). They've been growing like gangbusters, but this week I noticed some leaf yellowing and wilt on at least 3 plants out of 9.

Why are they yellowing? Is it anything to be concerned about?  I check the soil daily, and it's damp down to at least 4 inches.

I'm in zone 6a, if that helps any.

[image: potato wilt]

Comment: Just a guess and thus not an answer, but since tomatoes and potatoes are related (if memory serves they are both nightshades) this answer to my tomato question may be of use http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/244/tomato-leaves-started-yellowing-at-the-base particularly the second one about nitrogen being moved from the base up to the higher branches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tops of those plants look really healthy. You should be mounding up the soil around them as they grow -- these are taller than I've ever seen, so I have no idea what leaves should look like that low on the plant. By mounding up the soil you encourage the plant to grow more tubers higher up. Every 6-8" of growth, mound up the soil around them. Leave 3" or so of leaves poking out -- they'll keep making more top growth. This is why you hear about "potato condos" or growing in tall bags or trash barrels.

Comment: Indeed, 3 weeks later, they're as healthy as ever. A few of the lower leaves yellowed and then dropped, but the plants seem to be doing fine. In fact they just started flowering.