# Small tomato plants have purplish stems

Tags: plant-health, tomatoes

I have *Parks Whopper Cr Improved Vf1f2nt Hybrid* started from seed indoors.  The plants have healthy leaves and seem to be growing well, but their stems are rather purple.

Is this normal, or the sign of missing nutrients, or other issue?[image: Purple stem]

Comment: Doesn't look good: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/tomato-plants-got-black-stems-and-the-leaves-dry-out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm certainly no tomato expert - I've killed them seven ways from Sunday including dropping an entire flat of beautiful seedlings upside down and killing the whole lot of them - but that purple color is often, I've read, stress-related.  Perhaps due to light or temperature.

But you say that the plants have healthy leaves and are growing well.  That's good.  Personally, I wouldn't sweat it too much.  There's probably a tomato expert who can say more about what s/he thinks the problem is.  I'm not convinced you have a real problem at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Phosphorus deficiency probably

Comment: Please [edit] your post to explain **why** you think it's caused by a lack of phosphorus. Thanks and welcome to the site.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; if could also include suggested specific blends and types of nutrient, and amount per plant and frequency, watering, and soil recommendations, could all be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour] and browse through the [Help], especially [Answer] and [Ask], to learn more about how the site works!