# Why are my tomato leaves turning yellow, with brown spots?

Tags: diagnosis, vegetables, tomatoes, container-gardening

This is my first season trying to grow tomatoes. I bought three different types (cherry, heirloom,  and super sweet),  and planted them in a large pot on my porch. They seem to be getting a lot of sunshine, and the soil is mildly moist. They're starting to develop yellow leaves with brown spots and some of the smaller branches are dying.

Do they need Epsom salt or are they getting too much water? Do I need to move them to their own pots?

Comment: What size and type of pot? What planting mix? Soil drains poorly and you should be using a potting mix. Got a picture?

Answer (score 3):

We would need pictures for a definite diagnosis, but it sounds like your plants are showing signs of [**early blight**](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/13406/419). You can try these control methods:

> - Remove all leaves showing sings of early blight (yellowing, dry margin, large round dead spot,)
> - Do not touch the other leaves with the removed portions, or you hands until they are thoroughly washed.
> - Spray with a copper fungicide (like BONIDE© Liquid Copper Fungicide). Apply once every 5 days, and after any rain. Continue for 3-4 weeks, or until the plant stops developing the symptoms.

In the future, I'd start the plants in individual pots, from the beginning. That was you can separate disease at the first sighting.

Comment: Here in Ohio, I have noticed that many of my friends and neighbors who refer to diseased tomato plants as having blight are misdiagnosing Septoria Leaf Spot.

Comment: The biggest change in practice needed imho is to mulch the bed to make sure the spores don't splash up from watering..

Comment: @EvilElf the OP mentions having 3 plants, in one pot, so I answered accordingly

Comment: Oh I'm not critiquing, just adding. Spetoria photos vs Blight photos online should help. Action similar anyways.

Comment: @EvilElf it's true. The question could almost be closed as too broad. Pictures would help.

Comment: No pictures makes this tough.